# Flatten array in PowerShell

Tags: collections, powershell

Assume we have:

```
$a = @(1, @(2, @(3)))
```

I would like to flatten `$a` to get `@(1, 2, 3)`.

I have found [one solution](http://dougfinke.com/blog/index.php/2008/07/17/powershell-quiz-2):

```
@($a | % {$_}).count
```

But maybe there is a more elegant way?

Comment: For anyone less experienced and confused by this discussion, the flattening is done by `@($a | % {$_})`. The `.count` method reports 2 items for the original 3-dimensional array, and 3 items for the flattened array.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Piping is the correct way to flatten nested structures, so I'm not sure what would be **more** "elegant". Yes, the syntax is a bit line-noisy looking, but frankly quite serviceable.

**2020 Edit**

The recommended syntax these days is to expand `%` to `ForEach-Object`. A bit more verbose but definitely more readable:

```
@($a | ForEach-Object {$_}).count
```

Comment: Piping to `%` works, but not piping to measure-object, or `?`. It must be because of the way `%` processes input from a pipeline, rather than the piping itself.

Answer (score 14):

Same code, just wrapped in function:

```
function Flatten($a)
{
    ,@($a | % {$_})
}
```

Testing:

```
function AssertLength($expectedLength, $arr)
{
    if($ExpectedLength -eq $arr.length) 
    {
        Write-Host "OK"
    }
    else 
    {
        Write-Host "FAILURE"
    }
}

# Tests
AssertLength 0 (Flatten @())
AssertLength 1 (Flatten 1)
AssertLength 1 (Flatten @(1))
AssertLength 2 (Flatten @(1, 2))
AssertLength 2 (Flatten @(1, @(2)))
AssertLength 3 (Flatten @(1, @(2, @(3))))
```

Comment: Prefixing with a comma forces powershell to return an array even if there is only one item to return. Without the comma Powershell will unravel the array into a singe object of the same type as the array contents. This can be very confusing to people coming from other strongly types languages.

Answer (score 5):

**Warning:** See edit at the end!

This problem is probably most elegantly resolved with [the `.ForEach()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.1#foreach) introduced in Powershell v4.0. Performance-wise it has the advantage of not needing to construct a pipeline, so in some cases it might perform better.

```
> $a.ForEach({$_}).Count
3
```

If you already have a pipeline, the easiest way to flatten an array is to pipe it through `Write-Output`:

```
> $b = $a | Write-Output
> $b.Count
3
```

--

EDIT: The answer above is not really correct. It doesn't completely flatten arrays that have multiple nested arrays. The answer from @SantiagoSquarzon has an example of a deeply nested array that requires multiple unrolls:

```
> $toUnroll = @(@(0,1),@(2,3),@(@(4,@(5,6)),@(7,8),9),10) # 11 elements
> $toUnroll.ForEach({$_}).Count
8

> $toUnroll.ForEach({$_}).ForEach({$_}).Count
10

> $toUnroll.ForEach({$_}).ForEach({$_}).ForEach({$_}).Count
11
```

Or, perhaps more clearly:

```
> $toUnroll = @(@(0,1),@(2,3),@(@(4,@(5,6)),@(7,8),9),10) # 11 elements
### Unroll 0 times
> $toUnroll.ForEach({$_ | ConvertTo-Json -Compress})
[0,1]
[2,3]
[[4,[5,6]],[7,8],9]
10

### Unroll 1 times
> $toUnroll.ForEach({$_}).ForEach({$_ | ConvertTo-Json -Compress}) 
0
1
2
3
[4,[5,6]]
[7,8]
9
10

### Unroll 2 times
> $toUnroll.ForEach({$_}).ForEach({$_}).ForEach({$_ | ConvertTo-Json -Compress})
0
1
2
3
4
[5,6]
7
8
9
10

### Unroll 3 times
> $toUnroll.ForEach({$_}).ForEach({$_}).ForEach({$_}).ForEach({$_ | ConvertTo-Json -Compress})
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 3):

There are examples of *nested arrays* where piping to `ForEach-Object` simply can't handle them.

For example, given our nested array:

```
$toUnroll = @(@(0,1),@(2,3),@(@(4,@(5,6)),@(7,8),9),10)
```

If we attempt to pipe to `ForEach-Object`, the result would be:

```
PS /> $toUnroll | ForEach-Object { $_ }

0
1
2
3
4

Length         : 2
LongLength     : 2
Rank           : 1
SyncRoot       : {5, 6}
IsReadOnly     : False
IsFixedSize    : True
IsSynchronized : False
Count          : 2

7
8
9
10
```

`Write-Output` is also not able to handle the unrolling:

```
$toUnroll | Write-Output | ForEach-Object GetType

IsPublic IsSerial Name             BaseType
-------- -------- ----             --------
True     True     Int32            System.ValueType
True     True     Int32            System.ValueType
True     True     Int32            System.ValueType
True     True     Int32            System.ValueType
True     True     Int32            System.ValueType
True     True     Object[]         System.Array
True     True     Int32            System.ValueType
True     True     Int32            System.ValueType
True     True     Int32            System.ValueType
True     True     Int32            System.ValueType
```

---

Below we can see some examples on how we can handle the flattening of these *nested arrays* including a *one-liner [anonymous function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2)*.

- **Recursive [Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced?view=powershell-7.2)**

This technique unrolls our array in order.

```
function RecursiveUnroll {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [object[]] $Unroll
    )

    process {
        foreach($item in $Unroll) {
            if($item -is [object[]]) {
                RecursiveUnroll -Unroll $item
                continue
            }
            $item
        }
    }
}

RecursiveUnroll -Unroll $toUnroll
# Results in an array from 0 to 10
```

- ***One-liner anonymous function:***

The logic for this *script block* is the exact same as the function demonstrated above.

```
$toUnroll | & { process { if($_ -is [object[]]) { return $_ | & $MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock }; $_ }}
```

- **Recursive [Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes) Method (can be *static* or *instance*)**

Same as the recursive function example, we can expect the array to keep it's order. We can add that this technique **should be faster** than the recursive function approach since repeated function or script block calls is expensive, this is hinted in [**PowerShell scripting performance considerations**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations?view=powershell-7.3#avoid-repeated-calls-to-a-function).

```
class Unroller {
    [object[]] $Array

    Unroller() { }
    Unroller([object[]] $Array) {
        $this.Array = $Array
    }

    static [object] Unroll([object[]] $Array) {
        $result = foreach($item in $Array) {
            if($item -is [object[]]) {
                [Unroller]::Unroll($item)
                continue
            }
            $item
        }
        return $result
    }

    [object] Unroll () {
        return [Unroller]::Unroll($this.Array)
    }
}

# Instantiating and using using the instance method of our class:
$instance = [Unroller] $toUnroll
$instance.Unroll()
# Results in an array from 0 to 10

# Using the static method of our class, no need to instantiate:
[Unroller]::Unroll($toUnroll)
# Results in an array from 0 to 10
```

- [**Queue<T>**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=net-8.0)

This technique should be the fastest one, the downside is that we **cannot expect an ordered array**.

```
$queue = [System.Collections.Generic.Queue[object]]::new()
$queue.Enqueue($toUnroll)

while($queue.Count) {
    foreach($item in $queue.Dequeue()) {
        if($item -is [object[]]) {
            $queue.Enqueue($item)
            continue
        }
        $item
    }
}

# Using our given nested array as an example we can expect
# a flattened array with the following order:
# 10, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 4, 7, 8, 5, 6
```

- [**Stack<T>**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1?view=net-7.0)

Lastly, using a Stack we can ensure that the order is preserved, this technique is also very efficient.

```
$stack = [System.Collections.Generic.Stack[object]]::new()
$stack.Push($toUnroll)

$result = while($stack.Count) {
    foreach($item in $stack.Pop()) {
        if($item -is [object[]]) {
            [array]::Reverse($item)
            $stack.Push($item)
            continue
        }
        $item
    }
}

[array]::Reverse($result)
$result # Should be array from 0 to 10
```

Comment: Very interesting answer! I noticed that while `$toUnroll | Write-Output` didn't work, `$toUnroll | Write-Output | Write-Output` did. Of course, that just punts the problem further down the line. An even deeper array would likely cause the issue to recur.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .NET's String.Join method.

```
[String]::Join("",$array)
```

Comment: This question is about concatenating arrays, not strings.

Comment: I came here with the intention to flattening an array of strings - and this did the job :) And btw. this is as I read the title "Flatten Array in PowerShell". +1