# Flattening nested arrays in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Given this input:

```
$values = @(1, @(2, 3), $null, @(@(4), 5), 6)
```

What is necessary to create a clean iteration/pipeline over

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

?

Conditions:

- It should not include `$null` in the output.
- It should result in an empty array even if the input is $null or all of the input's values are $null.

Bonus:

- It should show `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` as the result of `ConvertTo-Json -Compress`
- It should preferably be clean and memorable, i.e. non-byzantine pipe manipulation preferred, no dependency on custom functions, if that is at all possible.

I've seen [Flatten array in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711991/flatten-array-in-powershell), the solutions there do not seem to fulfill the conditions.

Comment: Do you need to flatten only arrays? How about other types of collections?

Comment: A solution that supports all types of collections are highly welcome. The goal is to be able to iterate over, call `Select-Object` on, etc the whole thing without being disrupted by `$null` or affected by nesting depth.

Comment: I'm super tempted to build a recursive function but that would violate the bonus

Comment: @Matt If that is what it takes, well then so be it. I could have done that myself, but I was hoping for a "you're holding it wrong" type of answer that contains some kind of fundamental revelation about how Powershell does these things internally, or how one is supposed to do this in general.

Comment: @Tomalak recursion is the best way to handle this.  And you need a function to do recursion.  I missed the 'custom function' part of the bonus.  In the spirit of using the right tool for the job, I would use a recursive function.

Comment: _the solutions there __did__ not seem to fulfill the conditions_. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71641681/15339544) in that question includes different ways to solve the problem, including `Queue<T>` and `Stack<T>` (my preferred methods).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For completeness sake as it might help another user I wanted to include a *very* simple recursive function that covers most of your criteria except...

> It should preferably be clean and memorable, i.e. non-byzantine pipe manipulation preferred, no dependency on custom functions, if that is at all possible.

I am aware that *[you] could have done that [your]self* but maybe it can help someone else. I have seen this, when talking about PowerShell, referred to as unrolling arrays. If you continue your search that word might help bear more fruit.

Using `$input` how it was intended we make a rather simple function. If one of the elements passed is an array element then we call the function again until we are reduced to raw values.

```
function Flatten-Array{
    $input | ForEach-Object{
        if ($_ -is [array]){$_ | Flatten-Array}else{$_}
    } | Where-Object{![string]::IsNullorEmpty($_)}
    # | Where-Object{$_} would also work.
}
```

So a sample call would be

```
@(1, @(2, 3), $null, @(@(4), 5), 6) | Flatten-Array | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```

Which nets `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`. `$null`s are covered with one of several simple `Where` clauses.

Comment: Your `Flatten-Array` does not drop `$null`. Try this: `@(1, @(2, 3), $null, @(@(4), 5), 6) | Flatten-Array | % GetType`. It is `ConvertTo-Json` who drops `$null`.

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks. A simple where covers that. I was trying to keep it terse.

Comment: @Xalorous `$input` is an [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx). It does not need to be defined. Not sure why it is not running for you.

Comment: @Matt I learned about that after I posted the comment, and removed the comment.

Answer (score 13):

The `ForEach-Object` cmdlet (`%`) flattens arrays by default.

```
@(1, @(2, 3), $null, @(@(4), 5), 6) | %{$_} | ?{$_ -ne $null}
```

The output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with recursive command:

```
$values = (1, (2, 3), $null, (,4, 5), 6)

$values|&{
    process{
        if($null -ne [System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives]::GetEnumerator($_)){
            $_|&$MyInvocation.MyCommand.ScriptBlock
        }elseif($null -ne $_){
            $_
        }
    }
}
```

But you should be sure, that you does not pass something like this as input:

```
$values[0]=$values=,0
```

Comment: That doesn't *quite* fulfill the "non-byzantine" part, but it is very interesting and instructive. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** Don't use `$input` as a variable name, it's an automatic pipeline enumerator and it won't behave as you expect.

Two rounds of pipelining (ie. with `ForEach-Object`) will flatten that structure for you, `ConvertTo-Json -Compress` will automatically leave out the `$null` value:

```
PS C:\> $NestedArray = @(1, @(2, 3), $null, @(@(4), 5), 6)
PS C:\> $FlatArray   = $NestedArray | ForEach-Object { $_ } | ForEach-Object { $_ }
PS C:\> $FlatArray | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: `$input` was just a dummy name, I've changed that, thanks for the hint. What about N levels deep? Isn't there a way to do that that without prior knowledge of the nesting depth? Also, I want `$null` out *before* `ConvertTo-Json`, mentioning it was only to make obvious what resulting data structure I was after to begin with.

Comment: Since this is not recursive, it will not handle more than 3 levels.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive `Flatten-Array` function that does not use pipelining:

```
$values = @(1, @(2, 3), $null, @(@(4), 5), 6)

function Flatten-Array{
    param (
        [array] $inputArray 
    )

    foreach ($item in $inputArray){ 
        # skip $nulls
        if ($item -ne $null) {
            # recurse for arrays
            if ($item.gettype().BaseType -eq [System.Array]) {
                Flatten-Array $item
            }
            else {
            # output non-arrays
                $item
            }
        }
    }
}

Flatten-Array $values | %{$_.gettype()}
```

Comment: Mh, what's the benefit of not using pipelining?

Comment: You asked that it not include byzantine pipelining.  This is the simplest, easiest to remember solution that I could develop.  With a couple hours polishing this could be converted to an Advanced Function and be considered 'reusable' code.  If this was something I needed to do often, I would consider adding it to my profile or a custom module.  YMMV, but in scripting, I tend towards functions that return objects, while in CLI, I will use aliases and pipelining.

Comment: I didn't mean to say that I find pipelining byzanzine. I meant to say that I would not prefer byzantine pipelining, that's a difference. See PetSerAl's answer, eye-opening as it may be, for an example of byzantine pipelining.