# iterate through powershell double dimensions json object

Tags: json, powershell, loops, iterator

I have checked with foreach and foreach-object but unable to iterate any value out of it even using convertFrom-json, so I'm liitle bit clueless on this part - any idea how to iterate though every cell of it ?

```
[
    [
        [
            "test-1234",
            "2023-07-11T04:00:24+00:00"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "sb-00091",
            "2023-07-11T04:00:21+00:00"
        ]
    ]
]
```

and how to iterate and fetch every value from the below set aswell

```
[
    [
        [
            "test-999",
            "2023-07-13T04:00:21+00:00",
            [
                [
                    "checking"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: rolling back this question because it was asking more than what was originally asked.

Answer (score 3):

What you have in your Json files are nested arrays not cells, you can use a [`Queue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=net-7.0) to traverse the nested arrays until you reach the scalar values. The same logic can be used on both Json files presented in your question. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71641681/15339544) demos the different alternatives available to *flatten* nested arrays of unknown depth.

```
$json = Get-Content path\to\json.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$queue = [System.Collections.Generic.Queue[object]]::new()
$queue.Enqueue($json)

while ($queue.Count) {
    $items = $queue.Dequeue()
    foreach ($item in $items) {
        if ($item -is [System.Collections.ICollection]) {
            $queue.Enqueue($item)
            continue
        }
        "Item: $item"
    }
}
```

First Json outputs:

```
Item: test-1234
Item: 07/11/2023 01:00:24
Item: sb-00091
Item: 07/11/2023 01:00:21
```

Second Json outputs:

```
Item: test-999
Item: 07/13/2023 01:00:21
Item: checking
```

Comment: Thanks Santiago !! one more point is if I would like to iterate through and would like to get the corresponding value of Timestamp i.e. for test-1234 it is 2023-07-11T04:00:24+00:00 , then how should I need to update the loop ?
Looking for your update

Comment: I have updated this in the last part of my original Question as well

Comment: @MoneyTimes hi, that should be part of a new question, you're not supposed to edit the original one asking for more

Comment: I'm Sorry, but I am in deadlock situation, that's why asking for it, I have used foreach ($sublist in $data) {
        foreach ($item in $sublist){
        Write-Host ("the value is :"+$item)
        }
    } 

but it's not taking at all

Comment: Sqarzon - Sir, would you be able to take a look in that part plz ?