# looping through powershell of multiple dimensions json object

Tags: json, powershell, loops

I have checked with foreach and foreach-object but unable to iterate any value out of it even using convertFrom-json, so I'm little bit clueless on this part - any idea how to iterate though every cell of it ?
I have tried with the below but it didn't work out

> foreach ($sublist in $data) { foreach ($item in $sublist){ Write-Host
> ("the value is :"+$item) } }

```
[
    [
        [
            "test-1234",
            "2023-07-11T04:00:24+00:00"
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "sb-00091",
            "2023-07-11T04:00:21+00:00"
        ]
    ]
]
```

I would like to iterate through and would like to get the corresponding value of Timestamp i.e. for test-1234 it is 2023-07-11T04:00:24+00:00 , then how should I need to update the loop

```
a                            b
test-1234                  2023-07-11T04:00:24+00:00
sb-00091                   2023-07-11T04:00:21+00:00
```

Is there any book or online article available if I can go through it

If I have the below data structure then how should I iterate

```
    [
        [
            "test-1234",
            "2023-07-17T04:00:18+00:00",
            {
                "Code": 8,
                "Name": "running"
            }
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            "sb-00091",
            "2023-07-17T04:00:16+00:00",
            {
                "Code": 16,
                "Name": "running"
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

output should be in this way

```
a                 b                            c            d
test-1234       2023-07-11T04:00:24+00:00      8          running
sb-00091        2023-07-11T04:00:21+00:00     16          running
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [the suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76665497/712649) from your previous question to extract a flat list of values, then create a new object from each pair:

```
$json = Get-Content path\to\json.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$queue = [System.Collections.Generic.Queue[object]]::new()
$queue.Enqueue($json)

$extractedValues = while ($queue.Count) {
    $items = $queue.Dequeue()
    foreach ($item in $items) {
        if ($item -is [System.Collections.ICollection]) {
            $queue.Enqueue($item)
            continue
        }
        $item
    }
}

$results = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $extractedValues; $i += 2) {
  [PSCustomObject]@{
    A = $extractedValues[$i]
    B = $extractedValues[$i+1]
  }
}
```

---

This approach might not work if the data isn't uniform (eg. if the second value in the inner array might not be a string), but you could modify the previous solution to test for whether a given collection has a count of two and a string in the first slot:

```
$json = Get-Content path\to\json.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$queue = [System.Collections.Generic.Queue[object]]::new()
$queue.Enqueue($json)

$results = while ($queue.Count) {
    $items = $queue.Dequeue()
    foreach ($item in $items) {
        if ($item -is [System.Collections.ICollection]) {
            if ($item.Count -eq 2 -and $item[0] -is [string]){
                # we've reached a leaf value, output as object
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    A = $item[0]
                    B = $item[1]
                }
            }
            else {
                # otherwise, continue traversing the structure
                $queue.Enqueue($item)
            }
            continue
        }
        $item
    }
}
```

Comment: If I would like to sort out those data based on time column (like only those timestamps within 24 hrs would be selected ) - then where should I put the condition ?

Comment: @MoneyTimes Nothing stops you from sorting the results after you've collected them: `$results = $results |Sort-Object B`

Comment: And Sir, apology for pushing you - how would I iterate through the updated data structure - kindly if you show a way of it which I have updated in the actual question, please.

Comment: @MoneyTimes Like any other array or collection type - use `ForEach-Object` or a `foreach(...){...}` loop: `$results |ForEach-Object {Write-Host "Got value '$($_.A)' with timestamp '$($_.B)'"}`

Comment: if possible, if you can share some insight that how should I iterate through the last data items - that would be so so so helpful for Me

Comment: @MoneyTimes I'm not sure what you mean. If you want the last item in an array: `$array[-1]`

Comment: Sorry Sir, I have updated the output of that multi dimensional json object, once you are available - can take a look of it

Comment: @MoneyTimes [Ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) - and make sure you include all the actual details this time :)

Answer (score 2):

Similar approach to [Mathias's last example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76681887/15339544) but incrementing an index that is coerced into a `char` later (`65` would be `A`). Downside is that if arrays don't have uniform counts you would end up with not normalized objects or *objects not having uniform properties*.

```
$json = Get-Content path\to\stuff.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$queue = [System.Collections.Generic.Queue[object]]::new()
$queue.Enqueue($json)

$out = [ordered]@{}
while ($queue.Count) {
    $items = $queue.Dequeue()
    $char = 65

    foreach ($item in $items) {
        if ($item -isnot [System.Collections.ICollection]) {
            $out[[char] $char++] = $item
            continue
        }

        $queue.Enqueue($item)
    }

    if ($out.Keys) {
        [pscustomobject] $out
        $out.Clear()
    }
}
```

Output should look like:

```
A         B
-         -
test-1234 7/11/2023 1:00:24 AM
sb-00091  7/11/2023 1:00:21 AM
```

Comment: If I would like to sort out those data based on time column (like only those timestamps within 24 hrs would be selected ) - then where should I put the condition ?